# Which datatype to use for storing latitude and longitude

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

I have a question regarding of what datatype to use to store data in this format, for example :
51.4483, -0.1383.

I've been told to store it as varchar, but I'm not sure if that's suitable for me to use when plotting the markers.

The data are coordinates latitude and longitude which I later plan to use to map markers on a map.

Answer (score 0):

When using numbers in a `WHERE` or `ORDER BY`, they should be in some numeric datatype (`INT`/`FLOAT`/`DECIMAL`), not a text datatype (`VARCHAR`/`TEXT`).

If your lat/lng are consistently 4 decimal places (or less), then I recommend

```
Datatypes (lat/lng)  bytes    resolution    Usage
DECIMAL(6,4)/(7,4)     7    16 m     52 ft  Houses/Businesses
```

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices